# Strange issue about date and cookie

Tags: javascript

I write this code:

```
var Ec = new Date ();
Ec.setTime(Ec.getTime() + (365 * 24 * 3600 * 1000));
var Ed = new Date ();
Ed.setTime(Ed.getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000));
document.cookie="visit=" + Ed.toGMTString() + ";expires=" + Ec.toGMTString();

var Ea = new Date ();
Ea.setTime(Ea.getTime() + (24 * 3600 * 1000));
alert(Ea.toGMTString());
```

In the cookie are stored this:

```
06/26/2012 8:46 AM
```

and in the alert it display this:

```
06/26/2012 12:46 AM
```

And the current time in my country is:

```
 06/25/2012 14:46
```

Why ?
I want simply store in the cookie the current time + 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you're not in the GMT timezone.

When you execute `Ed.toGMTString()`, you're converting your time to GMT, which is why it differs from your local time.

`Ed.toLocaleTimeString()` or `Ed.toISOString()` might be nearer the mark.

Comment: So, how can I store in the cookie the current time + 24 hours indipendently from timezone ?

Comment: Expiry is done browser side. Don't convert to GMT when you store the cookie. Leave it in the local timezone.

Comment: I have just used your function without toGTMString but I get the same problem :(

Comment: Can you update your sample code and output, please? Maybe create a JSFiddle.